# new project in custom path

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

these commands must create new project in 'htdocs' folder:

```
cd B:\xampp\htdocs
composer create-project laravel/laravel project-name
```

but doesn't work and project be create in C:\Users\MyPC anyway!
how can I install project-name in B:\xampp\htdocs path?
By cd command, when i'm in C:\Users\MyPC : php artisan works. but when I move project-name folder to B:\xampp\htdocs, php artisan not works (can not find artisan)
How can I have project-name in B:\xampp\htdocs directory?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to edit httpd-vhosts.conf that is located in C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf and add following lines at the end of the file:

```
# VirtualHost for LARAVEL.DEV

<VirtualHost laravel.dev:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public"
  ServerAdmin laravel.dev
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working directory is a per-drive value. You also need to switch to `B:`.

Please compare (I've added the standard CMD prompt to highlight current working directory):

```
C:\Users\MyPC>cd B:\xampp\htdocs
C:\Users\MyPC>composer create-project laravel/laravel project-name
```

```
C:\Users\MyPC>B:
B:\>cd B:\xampp\htdocs
B:\xampp\htdocs>composer create-project laravel/laravel project-name
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : the command to get 'B:\xampp\htdocs' was not correct. that should be:

cd /d B:\xampp\htdocs

and it will work in windows os.